# Не работает template.render jinja2 без интернета

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

Я пытаюсь отправлять письма с использованием `jinja2`. При включенном `wifi` на ноутбуке, моё консольное приложение успешно работает, но при отключении `wifi`, я получаю ошибку:

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed
```

Ошибка возникает когда я вызываю `template.render`.

**Мой код:**

```
env = Environment(
                loader=FileSystemLoader('template'),
                autoescape=select_autoescape(['html', 'xml'])
            )
    template = env.get_template('mail_responsible.html')
    html = template.render(
        object_name=object_name,
    )
```

Есть ли пути решения этой проблемы и в чем ее причина?

Я пробовал полностью вычищать файл `html`, для того чтобы убедиться, что там нет ссылок на какие-либо ресурсы в сети интернет, которые были бы ему необходимы для отрисовки шаблона, но это не дало положительных результатов.

Я мог бы вложить содержимое html непосредственно  в тело письма, но это эстетически некрасиво.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что я не смогу подключить стили `css` в файл `html` используя атрибут `<link>` при отправке письма? Именно для этого мне необходим пакет `jinja2`, чтобы объединить `<styles>` и динамический контент.

**Весь код ошибки:**

```
[Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 90, in search_pandas
  File "mail.py", line 54, in mail_responsible
  File "smtplib.py", line 1045, in __init__
  File "smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
  File "smtplib.py", line 341, in connect
  File "smtplib.py", line 1051, in _get_socket
  File "smtplib.py", line 312, in _get_socket
  File "socket.py", line 822, in create_connection
  File "socket.py", line 953, in getaddrinfo
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed
```

Comment: Покажите полный текст ошибки

Comment: Ну и если вы внутри шаблона делаете что-то необычное, то шаблон тоже покажите

Comment: @andreymal, я добавил весь код ошибки в свой вопрос, шаблон может быть даже пустым, имею ввиду содержать только стандартный код, который формируется автоматически при создании файла html.

Comment: Текст ошибки указывает на то, что она происходит вовсе не в шаблоне, а в файле `PythonProjects\contracts-server\contracts\mail.py` — и вполне логично, что без интернета вы не можете подключиться к Яндексу

Comment: @andreymal, вероятно, я немного ввел Вас в заблуждение, я отредактировал свой вопрос, первоначально с этой ошибкой я столкнулся, при попытке отправить письмо во внутренней сети компании, но дополнительно попытался воспроизвести ее на другой машине, и с другими настройками подключения к почтовому серверу. Я полагал, что это одна и таже ошибка.

Comment: Ошибка всё ещё указывает на то, что она происходит в файле `mail.py`, а вовсе не в шаблоне

Comment: Спасибо всем за Ваши ответы, мой код сработал, но к моему сожалению, я так и не понял, что я изменил для этого.